# How to tell my if-statement to only accept integers?

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I want my program to tell the user that if (s)he enters a non-integer he should try again, instead of just terminating the whole main method like it does now. Pseudo code of problem part:

```
int integer = input.nextInt();
If (user types in a non-integer) { 
  ("you have entered a false value, please retry");
  then let's user enter int value
else {
  assign nextint() to integer and continue
}
```

Comment: Use do-while loop as explained in answer below by assylias & use commons apache's StringUtils class to determine if input is integer or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [a `while` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to re-execute that portion of code until the user enters a proper integer value.

```
do {
    input = read user input
} while(input is not an integer)
```

It seems you are using a `Scanner`, so you could [use the `hasNextInt` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29):

```
while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
    let user know that you are unhappy
    input.next(); //consume the non integer entry
}

//once here, you know that you have an int, so read it
int number = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: it seems to me that the OP doesn't know how to check if the input is or not an integer.

Comment: for the while-part would this be correct:
while(input != int)

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you are worried about the user entering in something other than an integer on input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer integer = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
    String line = sc.next();
    integer = tryParse(line);
    while(integer == null){
        System.out.print("The input format was incorrect, enter again:");
        integer = tryParse(sc.next());
    }
    int value = integer.intValue();
}

public static Integer tryParse(String text){
    try{
        return new Integer(text);
    } catch
    (NumberFormatException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of parsing the entry? You already call `hasNextInt` to determine if the entry is an integer or not...

Comment: @assylias Whoops, changed to what I meant.